# How to create nested route url supporting pod structure in ember?

Tags: ember.js

How can I create a route to support nested URL having format "/objects/1/fields/1".

I was able to achieve this with the following code but it violates the pod structure of my code.

```
this.route('fieldShow', {path: '/objects/:object_id/fields/:field_Id'});
```

Comment: Why would it violate the pod structure?

Comment: In the example I have given, I would not be able to structure the files of fields. All the file related to fields like for "show", "edit", "new" would have to be placed in the root of routes rather than conventional "fields" folder following pods structure.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by passing the path like this:

```
  this.route('fields', {path: 'objects/:object_id/fields'}, function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:field_id'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
 Router.map(function() {

        this.route('fieldshow', function() {
         this.route('edit');
          this.route('object', { path: ':object_id' }, function() {
            this.route('field', { path: ':field_id' });
         });
      });
    });
```

this probably helps you. you may ignore this.route('edit'); this is just to show you how it works